# Why am I getting value increase while recalculating an array?

Tags: javascript, cycle

I need to recalculate vales of array in JavaScript and I am trying to do it like this:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < totalNum; i++) {
          x = 3;
          if (chane[i]<rand) {
            chane[i+1] += chane[i];
            chane[i] = 0;
          } else{
            chane[i] -= x;
            chane[i+1] += x;
          };
```

`chane` array comes in with values `[15,4,4,0]`, and comes out as `[12,40,40,3]`. 
`totalNum` is 4.

I have been staring at this code trying to find where my newbie mistake hides... I am new to JavaScript, so this very well may be just some syntax error.

Comment: `rand = 3` Chosen by fair dice roll. Guaranteed to be random. http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: I have assumed 3 for debugging perspicuous. Could you contribute to the question in any way more?

Comment: Could you explain what output do you expect? And what is `totalNum`? Is it `chane.length-1`?

Comment: couldn't reproduce your output ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AVDN4/)) but you definitely trying to access the fifth item in the array, when there are only 4 items in it.

Comment: Yes `totalNum` is `chane.length-1` yet I had it already allocated so reused it.
I am hoping to create a model of flow by putting a random number instead of `x`. In this debugging variant what I supposed to get is `[12,4,4,3]`

Comment: is there anything else in the loop? where is its end?

Comment: If you make totalNum 3, you'll get that output (see jsfiddle provided by @basilikum above)

Comment: @gkovacs90 yup it is the end I just forgot `};` at the end of the code there.

Comment: the `;` should be forgotten here. It doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to convert your value to integer, and you should pass string value to your loop check this code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < totalNum; i++) {
      // convert to int by mul to 1
      chane[i]*=1;
      chane[i+1]*=1;

      x = 3;
      if (chane[i]<rand) {
        chane[i+1] += chane[i];
        chane[i] = 0;
      } else{
        chane[i] -= x;
        chane[i+1] += x;
      };
    }
```

if you set **chane = [15,4,4,0]** and set totalNum = 4, the result is: **[12, 4, 4, 0, NaN]** and **NaN** is for check last value because when i=3 then chane[3] equal with 0 and chane[i+1] equal to undefined and undefined multiply to every number is NaN, you can fix it with change upper bound (in your example:set totalNum to 3, fixed it with changing to totalNum = chane.length-1) or add some **if**

Comment: As suspected a syntax level error :) Thanks for additional tips too :)